# multivariate integral calculation in closed form

Tags: pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, closed-form-expressions

I am looking for a closed form for the below integral but since I don't have the necessary backgrounds I am not able to solve it: i know the final solution is in the form of modified Bessel functions and polynomials and also I know it might be related to moments of multivariate inverse gaussian distributions:
here is the integral

assuming z and y are vectors. and $\lambda$ and $\Gamma$ are matrices. $\Gamma$ can be diagonal though.

$U$ is a diagonal matrix containing $\sqrt z_i$ as its diagonal elements.

$$ U = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{z_1} & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots & \sqrt{z_d} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ \lambda = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_{11} & \cdots & \lambda_{1d} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \lambda_{d1} & \cdots & \lambda_{dd} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ \Gamma= \begin{bmatrix} \Gamma_{1} & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots & \Gamma_{d} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{z_1 ... z_d}}  \exp^{(-\frac{1}{2} y^T(U \Gamma U^T)^{-1} y)} \exp^{(-\sqrt{z}^T\lambda\sqrt{z})} \ \ \mathrm{d}z_1...\mathrm{d}z_d$$

thank you

Comment: Dear @c.Parsi: You say that you "know the final solution is in the form of modified Bessel functions and polynomials". If you know that there is a closed form, or have an idea of what it should be, it would be very helpful to add it to your question. Finally, does the vector $z$ consist of the integration variables $(z_1,\ldots,z_d)$ or is it an unrelated constant?

Comment: More to the point: if you know what the solution looks like, why do you ask how to get it? Is it homework? If not, you should give some background. If yes, you should move your question to stackexchange.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, actually from the similarities with moments of the inverse Gaussian pdf, I just guess that the closed form (if exists) should be in terms of bessel functions but I have now idea about the actual form. also the vector z contains the integration variables as its elements.

Comment: for diagonal $\lambda$ your integral evaluates simply to 

$$\prod_n \int_0^\infty dz_n z_n^{-1/2} \exp[-y_n^2/(2\Gamma_n z_n)]\exp(-\lambda_n z_n)=\prod_n (\pi/\lambda_n)^{1/2}\exp[-(2\lambda_n y_n^2/\Gamma_n)^{1/2}$$ 

--- no Bessel functions in sight.

Comment: thank you for the note, it was most helpfull, I am very much interested to the case $\lambda$ matrix is $\bf{not}$ diagonal or its bounded.